# Evaluating List Elements Against Multiple Criteria

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a List as follows:

```
List<Tuple<string, long, DateTime>> firefoxBookmarkPaths = new List<Tuple<string, long, DateTime>>();
```

And I have populated that list with two elements, each with filepath, filesize, and datetime properties, as shown:

```
{
    (W:\My Documents\...\places.sqlite, 
    5242880, 
    6/29/2018 5:37:29 PM)
}
{
    (W:\My Documents\...\places.sqlite, 
    10485760, 
    6/29/2018 6:30:05 PM)
}
```

My objective is to check each element in the list and return back the path property from the element that has both 1) The largest filesize and 2) The latest timestamp. Is there a way to evaluate both of these criteria without building two separate sub lists?

Comment: What about `OrderBy` ... `ThenBy`?

Comment: That the largest file would *also* be the oldest file would be a complete accident.  Very hard to write correct code when the requirement doesn't make sense.

Comment: OrderBy, ThenBy seems to have potential. Can you offer an example implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
return firefoxBookmarkPaths.OrderByDescending(o => o.Item2).ThenBy(o => o.Item3).FirstOrDefault().Item1;
```